# Excel column that contains semi-colon separated multiple names, need to filter rows that have multiple values, omitting single values

Tags: excel, filter

Filter the column for the rows contain multiple names. Omit rows that have single names.

Comment: Are the single named values followed by semi-colons as well? Sample data would clear up questions like these fyi

Comment: The first row contains- Jane; John; David; Second row contains - Mary; Third row contains - Lily; Dove; Lucy; Mike;

Answer (score 1):

Since individual names are followed by a semi-colon, you can deduce that the ratio between `names:semi-colons` are `1:1` i.e. **equal**.

Therefore, you should count the instances of semi-colons in a helper column and then filter by the results there rather directly on your name column.

---

To count semi-colons you can use the below formula which measures the length of the cell with and without semi-colons. The difference is simply the number of semi-colons, ***or equivalently***, the number of names present

```
=LEN(A1) - LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1, ";", ""))
```

---

In conclusion, you can

A) filter this column for values > 1 **OR**
B) you can nest the above function into a `IF` statement to reduce the above formula into two values for easier filtering

```
=IF(LEN(A1) - LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1, ";", "")) > 1, "Multiple Names", "Single Names")
```

[image]

Comment: I am running this formula which is working fine for first listed name int the cell. I would like to update the formula to 'Search' next name if the first listed name results #N/A.  =VLOOKUP(LEFT(F86, SEARCH(";",F86,1)-1),UserDepReport!A:R,3,FALSE). The first row contains- Jane; John; David; Second row contains - Mary; Third row contains - Lily; Dove; Lucy; Mike;

Comment: That is a different question and deserves a new post. This solution answers your original question